# Insert Statement Not Working in Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, ubuntu-14.04

I recently uploaded my MySQL database on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and I've now come across a problem where a stored procedure I've developed doesn't work correctly on the instance. It works perfectly fine on my XAMPP instance on Windows, so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is as I am unfamiliar with Linux and AWS.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_PopulateAbstract
(conID INT, eID INT, abs TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE existID INT;
    DECLARE abID INT;

    SELECT a.contributorID INTO existID
    FROM abstract a
    WHERE a.contributorID = conID and a.eventID = eID;

    IF conID = existID
    THEN
       --UPDATE statement works fine on Ubuntu instance
       UPDATE abstract
       SET abstract = abs
       WHERE eventID = eID and contributorID = conID; 
    ELSE
       --This statement doesn't work 
       INSERT INTO abstract
       (eventID, contributorID, abstract)
       VALUES (eID, conID, abs);
    END IF;

    SELECT a.abstractID INTO abID
    FROM abstract a
    WHERE a.eventID = eID and a.contributorID = conID;

    SELECT abID as abstractID;
END$$
```

This is strange because the `UPDATE` statement works fine on the Ubuntu instance, but the `INSERT` statement does not. The `INSERT` statement doesn't insert anything, and the last `SELECT` statement returns `NULL`. If the `UPDATE` statement is executed, the last `SELECT` statement does return something and data is appropriately updated.

I've ran the `INSERT` statement as a stand alone statement and it works fine, but it doesn't work in the Stored Procedure. What could be difference between the XAMPP instance, where it does work, and the Ubuntu instance where it doesn't?

Comment: at a time one statement execute. if 'if' statement execute so why 'else ' statement will execute. at at time if or else will execute

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the reason causing the `INSERT` statement to not be working, and that is something to do with the part of the Stored Procedure I left out of the original question thinking it wasn't the cause of the problem. Here is the full procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
    DECLARE existID INT;
    DECLARE abID INT;

    SELECT a.contributorID INTO existID
    FROM eventcontributor a 
    WHERE a.contributorID = conID and a.eventID = eID;

    IF conID = existID
    THEN
        --cause of problem
        SELECT a.contributorID INTO existID
        FROM abstract a
        WHERE a.contributorID = conID and a.eventID = eID;

        IF conID = existID
        THEN 
            UPDATE abstract
            SET abstract = abs
            WHERE eventID = eID and contributorID = conID; 
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO abstract
            (eventID, contributorID, abstract)
            VALUES (eID, conID, abs);
        END IF;

        SELECT a.abstractID INTO abID
        FROM abstract a
        WHERE a.eventID = eID and a.contributorID = conID;

        DELETE
        FROM abstractattachments
        WHERE abstractID = abID;

        SELECT abID as abstractID;
    ELSE
        SELECT -1 as abstractID;
    END IF;
END$$
```

In this full procedure, the problem is actually caused where I am re-selecting a value into the variable `existID`. For some reason, and now the real question, the Ubuntu instance of MySQL doesn't overwrite a variable value if it already consists of one. Maybe it's something to do with the version of MySQL being different from that on Ubuntu and that being on my Windows XAMPP.

As a result, the variable `existID` retains it's initial value and the nested `IF` statement tests as `true`, meaning that the `UPDATE` statement is actually being executed rather than the `INSERT` statement.

The way to fix this was to `DECLARE` another variable, aptly named `existID2`, and then use this variable instead of re-using `existID`.

Solution:

```
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
    DECLARE existID INT;
    DECLARE existID2 INT;
    DECLARE abID INT;

    SELECT a.contributorID INTO existID
    FROM eventcontributor a 
    WHERE a.contributorID = conID and a.eventID = eID;

    IF conID = existID
    THEN
        --using a new, empty variable
        SELECT a.contributorID INTO existID2
        FROM abstract a
        WHERE a.contributorID = conID and a.eventID = eID;

        IF conID = existID2
        THEN 
            UPDATE abstract
            SET abstract = abs
            WHERE eventID = eID and contributorID = conID; 
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO abstract
            (eventID, contributorID, abstract)
            VALUES (eID, conID, abs);
        END IF;

        SELECT a.abstractID INTO abID
        FROM abstract a
        WHERE a.eventID = eID and a.contributorID = conID;

        DELETE
        FROM abstractattachments
        WHERE abstractID = abID;

        SELECT abID as abstractID;
    ELSE
        SELECT -1 as abstractID;
    END IF;
END$$
```

It really boggles my mind as to why my local XAMPP instance of MySQL *can* re-use variables, but my AWS Ubuntu MySQL instance can not. It really doesn't make sense to me.